# Trying to create a confirmation dialog to a EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-preferences

I'm trying to add a confirmation dialog to an EditTextPreference in an Android app. I want it to ask "are you really sure you want to do this?" whenever they try to change the ID, but it must still be possible for them to do so when needed.

Now, I've tried looking around and have tried several solutions I've found but haven't been able to get any of them to work. The solution that seemed most promising was using this code:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PreferencesActivity.this).create();
```

To create a dialog asking for confirmation in the onSharedPreferenceChanged method if ID is what is being changed. The problem is that the builder wont let me use that context. I haven't really been programming for android for several years, but it feels like I'm missing something simple... What am I doing wrong?

```
public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.qta_check_in_settings);
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); ++i) {
        Preference preference = getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i);
        if (preference instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
          PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) preference;
          for (int j = 0; j < preferenceGroup.getPreferenceCount(); ++j) {
            updatePreference(preferenceGroup.getPreference(j));
          }
        } else {
          updatePreference(preference);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
      updatePreference(findPreference(key));
    }

    private void updatePreference(Preference preference) {
      if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        listPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntry());
      }
      if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference){ 
          EditTextPreference editTextPref = (EditTextPreference) preference; 
          if(editTextPref.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ID")){
              if(editTextPref.getText().equals("")){
                  editTextPref.setText(ID.randomID().toString());
              }
          }
          if(editTextPref.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("versionNumber")){
              if(editTextPref.getText().equals("")){
                  editTextPref.setText("Static.VERSION");
                  editTextPref.setEnabled(false);
              }
          }
          preference.setSummary(editTextPref.getText()); 
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Sagar It's not an error. *Kurodani* looking for solution how to display one more dialog (confirmation) while `EditTextPreference` is displayed.

Comment: @Dumbo, Kurodani is saying "The problem is that the builder wont let me use that context" I am trying to understand, whether some compile time error is shown or runtime. How does builder prohibit from using the context

Comment: @Sagar the error I got was "error: incompatible types: PrefFragment cannot be converted to Context"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add an `AlertDialog` in `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` listener.

#### I have tried this way:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
       .setTitle("Are you sure?")
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to change this preference?")
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               ((EditTextPreference)preference).setValue((String) newValue);
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           }
       }).show();
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: I tried using this solution from within the if(editTextPref.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ID")) in the "updatePreference" method, since I only want it for that specific preference, but it tells me that "variable 'preference' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". But I can't declare it final since I actually want to change it. how did you solve that?

Comment: I managed to get around the issue by making a new method to call and doing what I needed in there instead. That way I could actually build without getting errors. However, when I run it and then enter the preference activity the program crashes and I get the following error:
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"

Comment: @Kurodani I have to see the code. I mean how have you done it in the code. Without it I can't tell you what exactly could be wrong.